# How to create a clone of an object with some fields changed?

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object

```
const anObj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
```

I want to create a copy of it, but with some fields changed. I want to do this in one line. Currently, I have:

```
const anotherObj = Object.assign({}, anObj);
anotherObj.a = anotherObj.a * 100;
```

How can I combine these two in to one step so that `anotherObj` is `{a: 100, b: 2, c: 3}`?

Comment: why don't you just use the same syntax you used for anObj but assign the values from anObj in the desired way? And why do you want it to do it in one line? Edit: `const anotherObj = {a: anObj.a * 100, b: anObj.b, c: anObj.c};`

Comment: @MillieSmith Because I don't want to rewrite hundreds of fields

Comment: Is that the reason you want to do it on one line too? I don't see how that helps you avoid rewriting hundreds of fields?

Comment: You can wrap those two lines in a function and call it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const anotherObj = Object.assign({}, anObj, {a : anObj.a * 100});
```